# Is there a way in java regex to define a certain set of letters to look for?

Tags: java, regex

In other words, I want to make sure the user is entering either A, a, L, or l. My solution so far is this but I have not gotten the regex correct.

```
while(!qtype.hasNext("A| L") || !qtype.hasNext("a| l")){
    System.out.print("Please enter 'A' or 'L':");
    qtype.next().toUpperCase();
}
qal = qtype.next().toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Or you might want to change the logical OR into a logical AND. You can not use additional spaces in regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine if a string `str` is either `"A"`,`"a"`,`"L"` or `"l"` you can use

```
str.matches("[AaLl]")
```

If you don't want to use regular expressions:

```
str.equalsIgnoreCase("A") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("L")
```

---

Try something like this:

```
while (! (qal = qtype.next()).matches("[AaLl]"))
    System.out.print("Please enter 'A' or 'L': ");
```

Comment: I'd prefer to be checking the scanner input (qtype). any solution for that?

Comment: I'm now at this, however the scanner is not reacting to the input unless I input it, hit enter, and input it again(hitting enter again as well). Any thoughts?

Comment: Your value was already retrieved and assigned to qal inside the while statement.  Your last line could be changed to `qal = qal.toUpperCase()`.